# How do I collapse data frame rows if values are identical in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Lets say I have created the following data frame:

```
set.seed(215)
df <- data.frame(names = rep(letters[1:3], 4),
                class = sample(c("x","y","z"), 12, replace = TRUE))
```

This gives me the following data frame:

```
df
   names class
1      a     z
2      b     z
3      c     x
4      a     x
5      b     y
6      c     x
7      a     x
8      b     z
9      c     y
10     a     y
11     b     z
12     c     x
```

I want to collapse the rows such that each combination of `name` and `class` only appears once. In my example data above, I would have this:

```
df2
  names class
1     a     z
2     a     x
3     a     y
4     b     z
5     b     y
6     c     x
7     c     y
```

I have tried:

```
new_df <- df %>%
        tidyr::pivot_wider(., names_from = names, values_from = class) %>%
        tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%  
        pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from=rowname, values_from=value) %>%
        as.data.frame()
```

But, this results in the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
Values from `class` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} %>%
  dplyr::group_by(names) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  dplyr::filter(n > 1L)
```

The resulting df looks like this:

```
  name          1
1    a z, x, x, y
2    b z, y, z, z
3    c x, x, y, x
```

Please help me identify the simplest way to do this. I am trying to figure out a solution using base R or tidyverse, but am grateful for any help.

Thank you!

*edited to correct formatting of desired result.

Comment: `unique` from base or `distinct` from *dplyr* should do it.

Comment: I think you just want `df %>% dplyr::distinct(names, class)`.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the comments, the simplest way of doing this is either `unique(df)` or `distinct(df)` (both give the same result).